# Distribution Validation Failed for iOS App Submission

Tags: ios, xcode, submission

So I am in the process of submitting my first application to iTunes, I went through the entire process, and when I clicked distribute on my archive so that i could submit my app for approval, I got this image saying that a certain amount of things have failed. I fixed all the app icons that were missing (I didn't know that you had to have all of them, but I have them all now).

If possible, could you guys explain what each one means and how to fix it (I'm having a very large problem here since my app is actually part of a school project due in two days).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIO4T.png]

Comment: What part don't you understand? You are missing the 120x120 icon and your app is too big. It's 100MB, it needs to be less than 60MB.

Comment: This is my first time ever uploading an app. I'm sorry. Also, if its too big how do I make it smaller? I thought that the fifa app is over 1.5 gb   so why can't my app be over 60mb too?

Comment: How do I make the executable size smaller? (I came here for help because I don't know how to do/understand this)

Comment: If making your app available in the app store is a requirement for your project, you're probably not going to make it. The app review process usually takes several days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you including large files with your application?  In the Xcode Supporting Files folder, right-click on each file and select `Show in Finder` to see the size of each file. Are the biggest files absolutely necessary or a duplicate of another file?

Are there large arrays with several thousand or more elements within your code? Could the data be placed on a server external to your code and read in?